# closing ssh tunnel when using connection sharing without killing ssh?

Tags: ssh, connection, tunneling, share

I typically use ssh with connection sharing enabled; this causes any ssh tunnels I create subsequent to the initial ssh login to use that connection. Is it possible to close an ssh tunnel without killing the ssh process in such circumstances?

Comment: Just to clarify:  You close your ssh tunnel by killing the process.  Doing that closes all the other sessions that are involved in session sharing on that process. You are looking for a way to close the tunnel in a way that does not affect the other sessions.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. I tried tracking down the file descriptor associated with the tunnel port and closing that via gdb, but that (perhaps unsurprisingly) caused ssh to die with a "bad file descriptor" error.

Comment: I've never tried it, but the -O (capitol O) option seems to let you control the master.  The man page isn't clear how it works.

Comment: What kind of tunnel?  -L, -R or -w?

Comment: I'm starting the tunnel with -L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can terminate all the shared sessions by issuing `-O exit` from the client side.

`ssh -O exit masterhostname`

Sadly there is no way to terminate a specific session and leave the others running.

Sessions usually terminate naturally when the session is closed (EOF).  Tunnels made using -L and -R are always listening for new sessions and there is no way to indicate they should stop listening.